# Upload File once at a time in for loop in Angular 6

Tags: angular, file-upload, synchronization

I am trying to upload all selected files in Angular. I've created a service which pass the file as form-data to some api.

```
onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.uploader.queue.length; i++) {

      this.uploadedPercentage = 0;
      let fileItem = this.uploader.queue[i]._file;
      let f: FileDetail = { file: null, status: "", comment: "", uploadDate: new Date };
      f.file = fileItem;
      f.status = "init";

      if (fileItem.size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 <= 1) {
        this.uploadFile(f, i);
      }
      else {
        f.status = "error";
        f.comment = "Maximum 1GB is allowed";
        this.uploadedFiles.push(f);
      }
    }
  }

uploadFile(file: FileDetail, index: number) {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file.file);
    data.append('filename', file.file.name);
    var httpSubscriber : Subscription = this.service.uploadFileData(data).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      switch (event.type) {
        case HttpEventType.Sent:
          break;
        case HttpEventType.Response:
          file.status = "Uploaded";
          return true;
          break;
        case 1: {
          if (Math.round(this.uploadedPercentage) !== Math.round(event['loaded'] / event['total'] * 100)) {
            this.uploadedPercentage = event['loaded'] / event['total'] * 100;
          }
          file.status = "Uploading";
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Issue:
I want to upload file one by one and show progress of each file. if you see here in my example, I've taken for loop to upload all files and called `this.uploadFile` method that actually converts file to multipart and call service. but as it is asynchronous method, it doesn't wait for response (obviously) and it starts upload files all together. I want to upload this file one by one and show progress of each item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await` to wait `Observable` to finish.

First, make `uploadFile` method `async`. Then `await` the `uploadFileData` operation to complete. Note that `uploadFileData` observable is converted to `Promise`.

```
onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.uploader.queue.length; i++) {
         ...

      if (fileItem.size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 <= 1) {
        this.uploadFile(f, i);
      }

      ...

    }
  }

async uploadFile(file: FileDetail, index: number) {
    ...

    await this.service.uploadFileData(data).toPromise().then((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      switch (event.type) {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
```

A little stackblitz project that I created here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmbbfx

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: You can find the stackblitz link in the updated answer.